# i need to put a dropdown list into popup in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

i need to put a drop down list into a popup window
i created the popup and create the confirm button but drop down not shown correctly
what is the wrong with my code ?

```
 def delivery(self , instance):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        dropdown = DropDown()
        btn = Button(text='aaaaaa')
        dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(1, 1))
        mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
        
        box.add_widget(dropdown)  
        box.add_widget(Button(text='confirm' , on_press=self.confirm_transfer))
        popup = Popup(
            title='Delivery', 
            content=box,
            size_hint=(.4,.4)
              )
        popup.open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple errors:

- You left out the binding that sets the text of the `mainbutton` when a child `Button` is pressed.
- You added the wrong `Button` to the `content` of the `Popup`.

To fix it,  add the following line after `btn` is created:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
```

Then, replace:

```
box.add_widget(dropdown)
```

with:

```
box.add_widget(mainbutton)
```

So, here is a modified version of your code with these changes:

```
def delivery(self, instance):
    box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

    dropdown = DropDown()
    btn = Button(text='aaaaaa', size_hint_y=None, height=44)
    btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
    dropdown.add_widget(btn)

    mainbutton = Button(text='Hello', size_hint=(1, 1))
    mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)
    dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

    # box.add_widget(dropdown)
    box.add_widget(mainbutton)
    box.add_widget(Button(text='confirm', on_press=self.confirm_transfer))
    popup = Popup(
        title='Delivery',
        content=box,
        size_hint=(.4, .4)
    )
    popup.open()
```

Note that you are using `instance` in two places, and they conflict with each other. That does not cause a problem here, but if you modify this code sometime in the future you may run into a problem.